# Why can't strace or ltrace intercept the rand function

Tags: c, system-calls, libc, strace, ltrace

I'm using the following C program as an example ::

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("%d\n", rand());
}
```

Neither `strace` nor `ltrace` can detect the `srand` or `rand` calls. Why is that?

```
sumit@HAL9000:~$ gcc random.c -o random
sumit@HAL9000:~$ ./random 
1460823359
sumit@HAL9000:~$ ltrace ./random 
1937594805
+++ exited (status 0) +++
sumit@HAL9000:~/PlaidCTF/golf.so$ strace ./random 
execve("./random", ["./random"], 0x7ffede6c1b60 /* 56 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x556f5832e000
...
mprotect(0x7f5eaab03000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f5eaaab2000, 151418)          = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0x1), ...}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x556f5832e000
brk(0x556f5834f000)                     = 0x556f5834f000
write(1, "714715340\n", 10714715340
)             = 10
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: What platform are you on? What implementation of standard library are you using? As for `strace`, it shouldn't intercept `rand` nor `srand`, they are not system calls. I can not replicate on my platform - `ltrace` shows calls to glibc. I suspect something is with your `ltrace` or your envinment.

Comment: I think it's because strace traces "system calls and signals are events that happen at the user/kernel interface" and srand isn't itself a system call. It *uses* them but it is not one itself.

Comment: @JeffHolt yes you're right, `strace` isn't really supposed to catch it. But `ltrace` should, right?

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm on a standard Ubuntu 19.10 system, didn't really mess with the compilers or runtime environment, I don't think so. But yeah, there might be something going wrong with my environment that I don't know. Your `ltrace` shows calls to `glibc`, I see. Is there any way I can debug it, what's going wrong with my `ltrace`?

Comment: See the assembly. I see `callq time,__srandom,rand,_IO_printf` in `objdump -S ./a.out | grep -A20 '<main>'`. See what does the executable link with `ldd ./random`. I guess therre is a change the gcc inlines the calls, I wonder, I do not have ubuntu to test.

Comment: @KamilCuk There are calls to `time`, `srand`, `rand` and `printf` in the `objdump`, just like it's supposed to be. Hmm... I'll try this on an Ubuntu VM and see if this problem is with just my system.

Comment: On my ubuntu machine (linux 4.4.0-174 gcc 5.4.0), I cannot reproduce your problem. I see the ltrace command's output showing a call to time, srand, rand, and printf. Just like I would expect. The output of `nm random.o` shows unresolved references to printf, rand, srand, and time. So looking at the assembly is not required. If they didn't show up in the nm output, then their code is "inlined".

Comment: tl;dr of dupe: compile with `gcc random.c -Wl,-z,lazy -o random`.